# How to access the nested class within an API?

Tags: api, devexpress, blazor

The class TimeSheet has a variable of 'Name' and the nested class Status has a variable of 'Name'. When I try to call the Timesheet.Status.Name it's returning the value of Timesheet.Name. Both columns are returning with the same 'Name' of "Week # 18..." Instead of status returning as "Posted to payroll

Code for the grid

```
        <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(TimeSheet.Name) Caption="Name"></DxDataGridColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(TimeSheet.Status.Name) Caption="Status"></DxDataGridColumn>
```

Class code

```
    public class TimeSheetStatus
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TimeSheet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TimeSheetStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

API

```
 { 
        "Name": "Week #18   (Ending 2018-May-04)",
        "Status": {
            "Name": "Posted to Payroll",
            "Oid": 7
        },
```

Comment: Does the component allow you to bind an actual instance of a field instead of just using its name?

Answer (score 1):

DxDataGrid supports nested properties starting with [this version](https://github.com/DevExpress/Blazor/releases/tag/v0.4.0):

> - Bind to complex data objects

If it is not so in your case, please submit a [ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) to the DevExpress Support Center.

Comment: Yes, that came out 6 days ago. My answer was older than that, and directly from a DevExpress support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Or You can use below

```
 <DxDataGridColumn Caption="Status">  
            <DisplayTemplate>  
                @((context as timeSheet).Status.Name)
            </DisplayTemplate>
        </DxDataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently DataGrid does not support binding a column directly to a nested property. To solve the problem and display this data in a column, use DisplayTemplate:

```
 <DxDataGridColumn Caption="Status">  
            <DisplayTemplate>  
                @{  
                   TimeSheet timeSheet = context as TimeSheet;
                  <span>@timeSheet.Status.Name</span>  
                }  
            </DisplayTemplate>  
        </DxDataGridColumn>
```